# Numpy saves Integer Array as Float Array

Tags: python, numpy

My array of Integers gets saved as an array of Floats.

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
print(array)
>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

np.savetxt('labels.txt', array, delimiter=",");

test = np.loadtxt("labels.txt", delimiter=",")
print(test)
>> [1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6. 7.]
```

My created `labels.txt` looks like this:

> 1.000000000000000000e+00
>   2.000000000000000000e+00
>   3.000000000000000000e+00
>   4.000000000000000000e+00
>   5.000000000000000000e+00
>   6.000000000000000000e+00
>   7.000000000000000000e+00

But I expect the text to be `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: The default save format is: `fmt='%.18e'`.  The `savetxt` docs discusses altenative `fmt` values.

Comment: You can control the format that you save the array using `fmt` of `savetxt`, then you can also specify the `dtype` during `loadtxt` when you read back in.

Comment: `float` is the default dtype for `loadtxt` as well.

Comment: @prune, I am removing the duplicate.  That SO is about assigning elements in a `np.empty` array.  This is about writing values to a `csv`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `fmt` input of `%i` (integer formatting) to `np.savetxt`

```
import numpy as np

testList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
np.savetxt("testList.txt", [testList], fmt="%i", delimiter=",", newline="\n")
```

This gives the output `1,2,3,4,5`. Note that the input to `savetxt` is a list of lists. That is because the delimiter separates column values and the newline separates rows (so you need 2D to get the delimiters).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have anything confining you to np.savetext, then try using pickle:

```
import numpy as np
import pickle as pkl

path = r"path/to/dump.pkl"
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
b = pkl.dump(a, path)
c = pkl.load(path)
np.testing.assertequal(c, a)
```

Or in console if you feel more like it,

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> b = np.array(a)
>>> b
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
>>> import pickle
>>> pickle.dumps(b)
b'\x80\x03cnumpy.core.multiarray\n_reconstruct\nq\x00cnumpy\nndarray\nq\x01K\x00\x85q\x02C\x01bq\x03\x87q\x04Rq\x05(K\x01K\x07\x85q\x06cnumpy\ndtype\nq\x07X\x02\x00\x00\x00i4q\x08K\x00K\x01\x87q\tRq\n(K\x03X\x01\x00\x00\x00<q\x0bNNNJ\xff\xff\xff\xffJ\xff\xff\xff\xffK\x00tq\x0cb\x89C\x1c\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x00q\rtq\x0eb.'
>>> p = pickle.dumps(b)
>>> d = pickle.loads(p)
>>> d
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
```

This won't be a human readable file, but it answers your requirement.

---

or, just

```
with open(path, 'wb') as f:
    np.savetxt(f, a, fmt='%i', delimiter=",")
```

Which I personally favor less than the standard pickle

Comment: I'm not required to use np but I need it to be a `.txt` file

Comment: @Jonas Also added the csv option.